# How to use pyautogui over vps?

Tags: python, vps, pyautogui

I am currently struggling to get pyautogui to work with my vps.

The script runs fine locally, but when I attempt to launch the command on another computer outside of the network, I am getting the "screen grab failed" error.

I think this may be due to some permission issues, but not sure.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is graphics works at all at this server? Most probably you just don't have graphics on server instance at all. You need an X server in case of unix-like OS.

Comment: @PavelShishmarev it is running a copy of Windows 10 Professional. The web app is hosted with IIS.